# Silverlight navigation application with two frames

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight navigation application in which I have a Frame for the main navigation and a sub-frame in a sub-page where i navigate from one customer to his details. How can I add the navigation history from the sub-frame to the parent navigation history eg. the web browsers history?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should use is a single frame in the Main navigation of your application.
So you can 've all the history across your pages in the web browser.

Other pages can then use your Main frame like this

```
Frame frame =this.parent as Frame
frame.navigate(new Uri("/Views/Details.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```